# Reusable react-router-dom Link hrefs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to refactor `Link to=""` hrefs into a separate file so i can just plop them into any page that needs the same link. Can't find an example of how to do this when params are involved.

I am currently able to create a file that includes something like `export const urlManagePosts = '/posts/manage'`

Then I use it on a page like:

```
import {urlManagePosts} from '../../routes/posts'
...
<Link to={urlManagePosts}>Manage posts</Link>
```

This works fine. But when i need to introduce the `:id` into the url, I can't find a formatting method that works. I tried `<Link to={{urlEditPost}${post.id}}>Edit</Link>` where `urlEditPost = '/posts/edit/'` with no success.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: very strange that it wouldn't work with just a string format. I would imagine that it would be exactly the same thing as the to prop takes a string anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your code looks exactly like the example you've given:

```
<Link to={{urlEditPost}${post.id}}>Edit</Link>
```

then it doesn't work because `{urlEditPost}${post.id}` is almost certainly a syntax error (what does your browser's console say is happening?)  Your prop needs to be wrapped in backticks in order to concatenate two strings together:

```
<Link to={`${urlEditPost}${post.id}`}>Edit</Link>
```

Comment: or, use the object form of the prop: `<Link to={{pathname: \`${urlEditPost}${post.id}\`}}>Edit</Link>`

Comment: Weird. I had also tried the back-ticks before and they didn't work. I must have had a different syntax error with those. But this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do is have a URL format function

```
// posts.js
const urlEditPost = '/posts/edit/'

export function encodeEditPostUrl(id) {
  return `${urlEditPost}${id}`;
}


// Your Component
import { encodeEditPostUrl } from '../../routes/posts';

<Link to={encodeEditPostUrl(post.id)}>Edit</Link>
```

Also note as @Dan O mentioned `{urlEditPost}${post.id}` is an error. `Link` is expecting a string so you need to pass to give it

```
`${urlEditPost}${post.id}`
```